# Php Array - JSON structure - pushing data

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have 2 function and want to add data at first array structure, and on second function the data at second. 

 My result could to be a JSON like this:

```
{
  "Resource": "BestBuy",
  "IntervalTime": [
         { "SAT":[ "09:00", "10:00", "11:00" ] },
         { "SUN":[ "09:00", "10:00", "11:00" ] },
         { "MON":[ "09:00", "10:00", "11:00" ] }
  ]

}
```

My wrong code in PHP is this:

```
<?php
 foo();

function foo()
{
  $Days = array('SAT','SUN','MON');
  $Array = array(
       array('Resource'),
       array('IntervalTime')
      );
  // get Resource
  $resource = 'Best Buy';
  array_push($Array['Resource'],$resource);

  // go to add Open hours to resource
    foreach ($Days as $value) {
      AddTimeResource($Array,$value);
    }
  var_dump($Array);
}

function AddTimeResource($Array)
{
    $open_time = strtotime('09:00');
        $close_time = strtotime('12:00');
        $duratagame = $duratagame * 60;
        $output = "";
        for( $i=$open_time; $i<$close_time; $i+=3600) {
            // add interval time like 09:00 - 10:00 - 11:00 
            array_push($Array['Resource']['IntervalTime'],$resource);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code lack something:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $days = ['SAT', 'SUN', 'MON'];
    $Array = [
        'Resource' => null,
        'IntervalTime' => [],
    ];

    $resource = 'Best Buy';
    $Array['Resource'] = $resource;

    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $Array['IntervalTime'][$day] = AddTimeResource();
    }

    return $Array;
}

function AddTimeResource()
{
    $hours = null;

    $open_time = strtotime('09:00');
    $close_time = strtotime('12:00');
    for ($i = $open_time; $i < $close_time; $i += 3600) {
        $hours[] = date('H:i', $i);
    }

    return $hours;
}

var_export(foo());
```

Comment: fox91, i get my days from MySQLi fetch_assoc, than array got only the last Resource+IntervalsTime. How can push all resource+IntervalTime?

Comment: Complete your example code with your MySQLi code, maybe I can help you.